# Why does my progress bar not work? - Swift,Parse, I'm pulling my hair out over this one

Tags: swift, parse-platform, progress-bar

```
let userImageFile = object.valueForKey("profileImage") as PFFile
     userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            let image = UIImage(data:imageData)

            cell.parseImage.image = image
        }, progressBlock: {
            (percentDone: Int) -> Void in
            cell.progressView.progress = Float(percentDone)/100
        }


    }
```

Ok, so here's the problem. This line:

```
}, progressBlock: {
```

says consecutive lines must be separated by a ";"

says use of unresolved identifier "progressBlock"

says expected expression

Not sure why it won't let me. According to the Parse documentation this is the correct syntax for Swift progress bar.  I can properly download and view image without the progress bar.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the parens for the getDataInBackgroundWithBlock call, and have some mismatched braces.  Try this:

```
userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock ( {
    (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
        cell.parseImage.image = image
    }
    }, progressBlock: {
        (percentDone: Int) -> Void in
        cell.progressView.progress = Float(percentDone)/100
})
```

Or in swift, you can place the final block outside of the parens, dropping the last parameter:

```
userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock ( {
    (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
        cell.parseImage.image = image
    }
     }) {
     (percentDone: Int) -> Void in
     cell.progressView.progress = Float(percentDone)/100
}
```

Comment: RehcsifMit, when i try this it says that theres an extra argument "processBlock" in call. I found a google groups page where someone said this: 

    file.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ succeeded, error in
 
    }, progressBlock: { percent in       

    }) is the correct syntax for Swift. Not exactly sure what the call is referencing. This doesn't throw any errors.

Comment: Yeah try using my second version, or use my first version but omit the "progressBlock:" between the comma and the brace.  If that works I'll edit the answer above.  I usually just let autocomplete do the work for me.

Comment: I got it working using your second one changing the percent done to the syntax I posted in the comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with this and then realised you can only use the progressBlock closure with PFFileObject and then PFObject to associate the file to an object.

So make sure you save the file first with the progressBlock and then save it to the object.

**This is working with Swift 5.1 and iOS 14.7**

Partly from the [documentation](https://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#files) and some of my own code.

```
let str = "Working at Parse is great!"
let data = str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
let file = PFFileObject(name:"resume.txt", data:data!)

file?.saveInBackground({ (success: Bool, error: Error?) in
    // Handle success or failure here ...
}, progressBlock: { (percentDone: Int32) in
    // Update your progress spinner here. percentDone will be between 0 and 100.
}) 

let jobApplication = PFObject(className:"JobApplication")
jobApplication["applicantName"] = "Joe Smith"
jobApplication["applicantResumeFile"] = file
jobApplication.saveInBackground()
```